# Magento I-Banner - can't set "enabled"

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

There doesn't seem to be any docs available for this plugin (the I-Banner on magento).

I am trying to add a new banner to a page that already has a banner, I just need to place this banner at the top of the page (its an important notice), so I've logged into the CMS and gone to I-Banner > Add, added a new banner. It's status is set to "disabled" and I can't change it to "enabled", and it wont show up on the page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a dirty trick. Not truly a solution.

If you install FireBug for Firefox you can right click and "inspect" the drop down. You will see this...

```
class=" select" disabled="disabled"
```

Just click in the code and remove

```
disabled="disabled"
```

You should then be able to change the value of the drop down and save.

Comment: That was funny +1. There was actually an option "Is Active" and I had to set that to "Yes" to make it enabled. The confusion was there because on the list view it says "Enabled?" rather than "Is Active".